# Apply mongo db aggregation on object in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, aggregation

I want to apply the MongoDB aggregation on an object rather than a collection. Most of the time we do that we apply the aggregation stages on collection. But I want to apply this to the object. How to do it?

I tried to make a temporary collection and insert the object in it then apply the aggregation on it, but it was not worth doing, because every time you have to make a connection with the collection and do the above operation.